# Sequential heterogeneous functions executer

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, types, template-meta-programming

let's suppose that there are N functions that take different inputs and that return different values:

```
int h(int);
string g(int);
double f(string);
```

Of course it is possible to write something like:

```
f(g(h(4)))
```

Suppose now that I want to store these functions f,g,h into a kind of container like:

```
Container c;
c.add(h);
c.add(g);
c.add(f);
```

Given an input for the first function (an int in the case of f) I would like these function being executed in a sequential way, with each of them taking as input the output of the previous one.

Do you think is it possible in C++? possibly without using dynamic_cast and using C++11

Comment: Putting all the functions in a single container at run time is going to be difficult since they all have different types.

Comment: Does `Container` need to be modified at run-time? Is it OK if we add the functions at compile-time?

Comment: `Container` could have three fields to store the three different function pointers, `add` could be three overloaded setters that set the respective function pointer, and then finally `Container` has a function that performs the `f(g(h())) ` call.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I parsed the sentence as "without `dynamic_cast`, with C++11"

Comment: @NathanOliver I know that :/  Vittorio, ideally yes, but I'd be curious also in compile-time solutions. Sorry, I meant using "C++11"

Comment: @Blaze good idea.

Comment: @svoltron As for compile-time solutions (that don't require `std::function` overhead), check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076787/can-i-get-the-return-type-of-multiple-chained-functions-calls. The question there is how to get the final type, but the solution just builds the call expression and then does a `decltype`, so just skip the latter.

Comment: @MaxLanghof very interesting indeed thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Container` needs to be modifiable at run-time, you can achieve this with `std::any` (or `boost::any`):

```
struct Container
{   
    std::vector<std::function<std::any(std::any)>> _fns;

    template <typename R, typename A>
    void add(R(*f)(A)) 
    { 
        _fns.emplace_back([f](std::any x) -> std::any
        {
            return {f(std::any_cast<A>(x))};
        }); 
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::any call(T x)
    {
        // TODO: replace with recursive version
        return _fns[2](_fns[1](_fns[0](x)));
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
int h(int x) { return x; }
std::string g(int x) { return std::to_string(x); }
double f(std::string x) { return x.size(); }

int main()
{
    Container c;
    c.add(h);
    c.add(g);
    c.add(f); 

    std::cout << std::any_cast<double>(c.call(5)) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

> 1

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RayO3EEHPZMkG3j5)

---

Possible recursive implementation:

```
template <typename T>
std::any call_impl(T x, const std::size_t next)
{
    return next == _fns.size() - 1 
        ? _fns[next](x) 
        : call_impl(_fns[next](x), next + 1);
}

template <typename T>
std::any call(T x)
{
    return call_impl(x, 0);
}
```

Comment: really interesting solution Vittorio

Comment: Only doubt is the performance of std::function :/ Also the TODO part is something I'm wondering how to do right now eheh

Comment: @svoltron: You need type erasure of some sort. It's easy to reach for `std::function` rather than try to roll your own.

Comment: @svoltron: added a possible implementation of the TODO part. It seems to work but haven't tested all edge cases.

Comment: Great job @VittorioRomeo, it seems working, I'll check it out

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: [here is another recursive impl](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EC0GWPJGtPh55KHj), probably you can do better.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a side note but I made something very similar for fun during the holiday season. It's too much code to fit here but you can check the code [here](https://github.com/MaLarsson/functional/blob/master/include/chain.hpp) or a live version [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FYavsE25EOuMj9wV).

basically it's a function which returns a lambda capturing all the functions to invoke. This allows you to write the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "chain.hpp"

int f(int x) { return x; }
std::string g(int x) { return std::to_string(x); }
double h(std::string x) { return x.size(); }

int main() {
    auto function = fn::chain(f, g, h);
    std::cout << function(5) << '\n'; // prints 1

    return 0;
}
```

It will also try expanding retured tuples with std::apply if std::invoke does not work. This makes the following code valid:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#include "chain.hpp"

int main() {
    auto test = fn::chain([](int i, int j) { return i + j; },
                          [](int i) { return i * 2; },
                          [](int i) -> std::tuple<int, int> {
                              return {i, i};
                          },
                          [](int i, int j) { return i + j; });

    std::cout << test(1, 2) << '\n'; // prints 12
}
```

As I said, this was just a fun experement but maybe it will be helpful!